# regroup rows by value in a table and return a counter of the line collapsed

Tags: r, group-by

i'm stuck with this little problem:

[df sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wreaj.png)

i want to collapse the column UnstableDependenciesPackage and i know i can do it with the function group_by

```
UD %>% group_by(UnstableDependenciesPackage, version, project, Type)
```

the problem is that i want to summarize those occurences in the NumBadDep column, so i'll get for example:

```
org.apache.tools.ant.util - 1

org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs - 3

org.apache.tools.ant.types - 2
```

and so on. But i miss the second step of my instruction

Comment: So do you want to count the occurrences of each unique combination of `UnstableDependenciesPackage, version, project, Type` ?

Comment: yeah, and collapse them in a single row for each occurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a count of occurrences for each unique combination of `UnstableDependenciesPackage, version, project, Type` you could use `summarize` and the `n()` function.

`UD %>% group_by(UnstableDependenciesPackage, version, project, Type) %>% summarize(count = n())`